# How to query all task which are having relatedto(whatId) as Account or Contact

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, soql, apex

I am using an soql query to get tasks.  My requirement is to get all tasks which are related account or contact object.  Also few other fields inside Account or contact object whichever the  object related. Is there a simple way instead of writing multiple queries.

Answer (score 3):

Please provide more specific information next time. Generally speaking you can refer to a parent object by reference name followed with a dot. Here is an example

```
Select Account.Name, AccountId From Task Where Account.Name = 'John'
```

Here Account is the name of the reference (from task) and AccountId is the referencing field.

Comment: [Select t.subject,t.Description,t.Id, t.WhatId  From Task t  ] is my query but I require only those tasks related to Account or contact other way what field should contain Account or contact id

Comment: So it should be Where AccountId != null Or WhatId != null

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little unclear.  Are you looking for all TASKS related to *any* ACCOUNT or CONTACT or related to *specific* ACCOUNTS or CONTACTS?

If the former, try

```
    SELECT Id, Subject,
    FROM TASK
    WHERE
        What.Type = 'Account' OR
        Who.Type = 'Contact'
```

if the latter, use the `IN :list` syntax already suggested by Moti.  The `What.Type` is useful, as opposed to `AccountId!=null`, because it will not return TASKS associated with, for example, OPPORTUNITIES (if you want that behavior, use `AccountId!=null` and maybe drop the `Who.Type` if you associate all CONTACTS with OPPORTUNITIES, as it would be redundant).

In either case, your issue will be pulling specific data from CONTACT whos, as polymorphic fields only allow access to a limited number of fields.  Can't seem to find that list right now.  I don't believe old SOQL supports the kind of the syntax to do that in one query--that's why SOQL polymorphism made such a bang--though I could be wrong.

Now, if you have [SOQL TYPEOF](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_typeof.htm) [available to you](http://blogs.developerforce.com/tech-pubs/2012/09/soql-polymorphism-or-how-i-learned-to-love-the-polymorphic-relationship.html), you should be able to do something more interesting like:

```
    SELECT Id, Subject,
    TYPEOF What
        WHEN Account THEN AccountNumber
    END,
    TYPEOF Who
        WHEN Contact THEN FirstName
    END
    FROM Task
    WHERE
        What.Type = 'Account' OR
        Who.Type = 'Contact'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

select {column list] from task where parentid in (select id from account where ...) or parentid in (select id from contact where ...)

Alternatively, if you're inside Apex and already have the contact or account ids in a list (we'll use idList), you can use:

select {column list] from task where parentid in :idList

Comment: Sorry I cannot use  the account or contact ids to filter the query. I just want all tasks where what field contains Account or Contact ids. Smply tasks related to Account or Contact object